# Program compile, but it is not performing like i want it too

Tags: c#, android, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I am trying to get progam to develop math probems so that my user can answer them. I ran the program by itself and it displayed buttons for me to click with the number on them increasing. Can anyone please help me solve this problem. The part of the program i am concern about is the beginging of the int Correctcount. Please Help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;


namespace Jagtutor
{

    [Activity(Label = "Addition")]
    public class AdditionsActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Second);

            var label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.screen3Label);
            label.Text = Intent.GetStringExtra("ModuleData") ?? "Data not available";

            {
            int correctCount = 0;
            int count = 0;

                 while (count < 10);
                {
                    Random gen = new Random();
                    int num1 = gen.Next();
                    int num2 = gen.Next(); 


                    Console.Write("What is");
                    Console.Write(num1);
                    Console.Write( " - ");
                    Console.Write( num2);
                    Console.Write( "?");
                    int answer = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (num1 + num2 == answer) {
                        Console.Write(" Your are Correct!\n");
                        correctCount++;

                    }
                    else
                        Console.Write( "Your answer is wrong" );
                        Console.Write(num1);
                        Console.Write(" + ");
                        Console.Write(num2);
                        Console.Write("should be ");
                        Console.Write(num1 + num2);
                        count++;
                }
            }

        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you be missing { } around the body of the last `else`?